# Windows 7 Installation hangs at "Installing Features"

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I'm doing a Windows 7 install from a USB, but I'm stuck trying to finish the install. It finished with "copying windows files", "expanding windows files", and it's stuck on "installing features". Whenever the installer reaches this point the usb stops lighting up, which I'm assuming its because there is no features to install. It still needs install updates and complete installation. and I can't use the CD since the CD drive is not working.

I'm using the same image file that I have on a CD (which works fine). I chose to install the Home Basic version. The image file I'm installing is en_windows_7_with_sp1_debug_checked_build_x86_dvd_619602.

I cant use the CD since the CD drive is not working. I'm using a HP Presario F700. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your usb have compatible issues -- when it starts to install "features" it may picking up some wrong drivers for your usb drive, which results in disconnected the usb drive...

Comment: I reformatted to ntfs before i burned the image to usb. any suggestions?

Comment: What tool are you using to burn the image? the Microsoft one?

Comment: No i used ISO to usb, i now decided to use win32 disk imager.

Comment: From what i read it will load as a img file and not a iso file

Comment: Try this: http://wudt.codeplex.com/

Comment: why do you want to install a debug build of Windows7? Are you a driver developer?